# Removing the tableHeaderView from UITableView

Tags: iphone

This is kind of weird! When I run the app on simulator it works fine but on the device it does not remove the tableHeaderView. Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete == editingStyle)
    {

        BOOL success = [Service deleteNoteByNoteId:note];

        if(success)
        { 
            [self updateTableViewHeader];
        }
    }

}

-(void) updateTableViewHeader
{
    if([self.selectedVegetableGarden.notes count] > 0)
    {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [self createSharingView];
    }
    else
    {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
    }
}
```

The line self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil gets triggered but it never removes the table header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is the right way to do it. You're nilifying a view that your table view is managing. Why don't you try instead returning either your custom view or nil form `UITableViewDelegate`'s method `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`. I believe that's the right way to do it. You can ask the OS to call that method by executing the following line:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The weird thing was that it worked on the simulator. Your approach is way better and I am going to use that! Thanks!

Comment: Very strange indeed. You can never rely 100% on the simulator :S. I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Question is about table's header view , not about header for the section.